# MP3 player for podcasts

Tags: audio, mp3-player

I'm looking for an MP3 player mainly for listening to podcast.

Must have features:

- USB-C/MicroUSB/MiniUSB connector (for data transfer)
- 512 MB internal memory or more
- Buttons for seeking backward/forward 2-5 seconds (in case of missed words)
- Easy to handle in a pocket (without looking at it)
- Delete files from memory function
- Linux support

Nice to have features:

- Standard/replaceable batteries (AA/AAA)
- Can be used during charging (if battery is not AA/AAA)
- Bookmarking, advanced bookmarking function (mark files as listened, etc.)

Comment: Is AA/AAA batteries really more important than internal battery?

Comment: @enderland: It's nice to have as internal batteries tend to die after a few years, usually hard to replace them or buy replacement ones but you can buy AA batteries in every shop.

Comment: Why do you want a microUSB cable when you will use replaceable batteries?

Comment: @Firepower0701: For uploading mp3 files/podcasts :)

Comment: That makes sense. I was thinking of something more like an SD card transfer. But why do you want to charge replaceable batteries?

Comment: @Firepower0701: I've updated the question, nice to have features are rather contradictory together.

Comment: About it being microUSB - would one of the other "small" USBs like miniUSB or USB Type C have been OK?

Comment: @AJM: You are right, I've updated the quite old question.

Comment: Thanks. If you're still looking for a similar player this many years on... 1GB and 2GB versions of the iRiver T60 sometimes show up on eBay. They've got miniUSB, you use a sort of joystick button for the forward/backward skip as mentioned (it may be less than 5 second by default, but settings let you change that and 6 is close to 5.) I reckon it's easy to handle in a pocket, but your milegae may vary there. "Delete files" - yep, when they're not playing, highlight file and press the A/B button. Linux support... HELL YES! And finally, they use AAA batteries.

Comment: There is also a 4GB version, but it's been a long time since one of those was on eBay. There may possibly have been an 8GB, I don't know for sure. They last a long time - I got mine in 2008 and was still using it when I lost it on a train this February.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about dedicated MP3 players but you can buy any cheap prepaid Android phone and use the app of your preference.  I really like DoggCatcher, but there are many other podcast apps to choose from.

I recently bought a $15 LG something-or-other prepaid Verizon phone and use it exclusively for podcasts and using email over WiFi.

Some headphones have additional controls which can control your media player app.